# This dependency was not found: * core-js/es6/array in ./node_modules/cache-l

Tags: javascript, node.js, core-js

This dependency was not found: * core-js/es6/array in ./node_modules/cache-l

This dependency was not found: * core-js/es6/array in ./node_modules/cache-l

Answer (score 0):

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                  2:00:17 PM

This dependency was not found:

- core-js/es6/array in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Mine/SellGoods.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save core-js/es6/array

This is the error message，After the dependency package is installed, an error occurs when starting the project。